# New module, why doesn't default.xml frontend layout apply blocks to index_index path? [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2

[SOLVED]Module's index_index.xml layout file was missing layout="[example#cols]" on the page node.

I've just made a module with a controller and routes, the page loads fine and some head elements are present... however they are no blocks on the page - is this normal? Why doesn't default.xml layout apply to this page (defined in other places)

I have no layout files in this module yet.

Visual of the question:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean there are no blocks? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Updated Marius.

Comment: My Index_Index controller does this:
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

Is this why default.xml from other places isn't applying here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is normal behavior, but I think this happens because there is no layout set by default (1column, 2columns-left, ...).

If you create the layout file with just this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

</page>
```

you should be able to see something on the left side of the page.

Comment: I just beat you to it! Thank you very much Marius.